# Rails 4.0.1 form.select prohibits form execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, http, select

```
<%= f.label :level %><br />
<%= f.select :level, options_for_select([["User", 1], ["Administrator", 2]]) %>
```

I have the given select drop down and with it the form returns `302 Found` response, but without it, the form updates. If I try to create a new record, it's being made, but the field `level` is blank. Since I generated it using `scaffold` and updated only the input type from `text` to `select`, seems quite weird. What could cause that and how can I fix it?

**Controller:**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :surname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :level %><br />
    <%= f.select :level, options_for_select([["User", 1], ["Administrator", 2]]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... it looks like your User is saving successfully, but the `level` you set isn't being persisted. Maybe something is happening at the model level? Can we see your `User` model?

Comment: Updated the post so that you could see. No error is being thrown out anywhere and upon submit the form gets updated and a notice says that the user was updated successfuly, but the `level` is still blank.

Comment: Model only has `has_secure_password` in it. I haven't even got to the validation part yet.

Comment: It might not be a validation issue. You might have accidentally made `level` a virtual attribute, for example. Then it'd only be set on the user for the duration of the request and forgotten immediately after.

Comment: Okay, I just regenerated the scaffold and it works now. Don't know what the issue was though.

Comment: It may have not actually been a column in your DB, and only `attr_accessible` in your model. We could've confirmed that by looking at your `db/schema.rb`. Anyway, glad it's working now!